# Speed up report with multi value parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that is running incredibly slow when i add mutli value parameters. Never really had any proper training on Reporting Services so would like some guidance please on whether i'm following the correct protocols for creating reports and how i can improve the performance.

The report has 5 datasets - none of these are stored procedures, each query takes about 5 seconds to run in SQL management studio 2012 and returns around 4000 rows.

There are 5 parameters - 1.Date From  2.Date To  3.Country  4.Town  5.LocalAuthority

My parameters are set in each query like the following

```
where Date between @Date From  and @Date To
 and Country in (@Country)
  and Town in (@Town)
   and LocalAuthority in (@LocalAuthority)
```

The report runs fine without parameters and works well with just the country parameter but when i add in the others that's where things really begin to slow up, to the point where it will just timeout.

The report itself is just showing a few tables with a couple of filters added in them

I'm wondering whether it would be more suitable to try and create just one query rather than having lots of datesets? Anyway any help would be greatfully appreciated, hope i've included enough information.

Comment: I doubt that you `in` expressions are doing what you expect.  The are pretty much equivalent to `=` rather than `in`.  In other words, your query as written would not seem to work.

Comment: I would make sure that the parameters are returning a properly indexed column for the value. Also, run each dataset separately and try to do some performance tuning on each of them.

Comment: Thanks bjones, if I'm understanding your first point correctly then my country and town columns are coming from a case statement, could this be slowing things?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what values are being returned from your queries, but there is certainly a chance it is affecting performance. I would check the query plan for each.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really comment on your datasets/SQL performance without seeing what you are doing but can help you with multi-valued parameters.

Ideally, you should use a `split function` that will convert your multi-valued parameter values to the multiple values so that you can use `IN` operator. If you don't have any split function, try converting you multi-valued parameter to a temporary table and then `JOIN` the temp table to your main table. This will make life easy.

For example, if you have the following variable:

```
DECLARE @Countries VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Australia,France,New Zealand,United Kingdom'
```

Resulting:

```
SELECT @Countries AS Countries
```

As

```
Countries
----------
Australia,France,New Zealand,United Kingdom
```

The following chunk of `SQL`:

```
DECLARE @Countries VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Australia,France,New Zealand,United Kingdom'
CREATE TABLE #Countries (Country  VARCHAR(30));

DECLARE @Insert VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #Countries VALUES ('''+REPLACE(@Countries,',','''),(''')+''');';
EXEC (@Insert);
```

Will convert the mutli-valued `@Countries` variable to a temp table. 
Resulting:

```
SELECT Country FROM #Countries
```

As

```
Country
--------
Australia
France
New Zealand
United Kingdom
```

And now, you can `JOIN` this temp table with your main table. Try this and let us know if you can see some difference.

Comment: Adding `IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Countries') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Countries;` line at the beginning of the above code will delete the temp table before you rerun the SQL each time. In case if you don't know